# Are refresh token necessary?

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I have been searching lately about refresh tokens and access tokens with rotation and something hit me.

Why not just use one token instead of access token and refresh token? Include in that token payload  (claims) a validation date, and make the validation period very low ( just like access tokens ) and the expiration date very high ( just like refresh tokens ).

If the validation date exceeds the date on the server but did not expired, the server issues a new token and invalidate the old one ( by whatever mean like a blacklist of tokens etc just like when AT expires and new ones are issued using Refresh token) , and if the token expires then the server simply reject the request and ask for authorization ( just like when refresh tokens expires ).

If this approach works then why do we use 2 tokens which makes the dev process harder ?

Comment: You are assuming that every process that is provided with an access token should be entitled to self-refresh it. This might not be the case.

Comment: and why not ? I think it would be more secure like that

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting something.

Refresh tokens are stored on the server.  Access tokens are not.  Access tokens are self contained.  This is why they are referred to as bearer tokens.  The bearer of the token is granted access.

Which means if an access token is stolen by a malicious party, they can be used as long it has not expired.  Access tokens are considers safe because of their limited life span.

In order to use a refresh token in order to request a new access token. You need to have the client id, client secrete that was used to cerate it. You also need to be able to listen to one of the valid redirect uri's for the refresh token response.

Comment: the one token is also self contained and short lived too (due to the validation date ) and when you want to refresh it ( just like you said with providing the RT to a specific URI to generate an AT  ) you just have to send the token to the specific URI to generate a new one ,you might say if the token is stolen then the malicious user can use it infinitely unless the server invalidates it , the same thing can be said about RT and the same mechanisms could be used for protection like blacklist of old tokens. I still do not see the benefits of using 2 tokens.

Comment: AA malisons user can not use the refresh token with out the client id, the client secrete and access to a valid Redirect uri within the project where the consent will be returned to.

Comment: According to auth0 in this blog https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/  : "All those who hold the refresh tokens have the power to get new access tokens whenever they want. "They" could be legitimate users or attackers." I do not understand your point when you said "cannot use the refresh token without the client id, the client secrete.." as long as they have a valid refresh token they can send it to the RT URI like '/api/refreshToken' and get an access token is not that right ?

Comment: To get a new refresh token you must pass the client id, client secrete and the response is returned to the application at a valid redirect uri end point.  So a hacker would have had to steal your refresh token, client id, client secrete and still have access to the server at the location of the redirect uri endpoint.    If you want to understand the flow watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w